# Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, show that there's no probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ which ...

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, show that there's no probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ which just takes on the values $0$ and $1$ and we have $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt**

We know that probability measure have to fulfill $\mu(\Omega)=1$ and they're $\sigma$-addtive. It is true that $$[0,1]=\bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]$$ ... so $$\mu([0,1])=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]\right)=\underbrace{\mu(\{1\})}_{=0}+\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\underbrace{\mu\left(\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]\right)}_{=0 \,(*)}\neq 1$$

$(*)$ this can only take on the value $0$ because if it were the case it is $=1$, it would mean that $[1/n,1]=\Omega$ which is not the case for all $n$. Is that correct?

Comment: $\sigma$-additivity applies to *mutually disjoint* family of events, but your sets $[1/n, 1]$ are not mutually disjoint. So the argument is not true. Also, how do you know that $\mu([1/n, 1])=0$?

Comment: And don't forget $\{0\}.$

Comment: You seem to be discussing the existence of a probability measure  that is on [0,1], **not** "on" the power set. Rather, you are discussing a  whose *sigma algebra* is the power set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose such a probability measure $\mu$ exists, and define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ f(x) = \mu((-\infty, x] \cap [0, 1]). $$

We make several observations:

1. $f(x) \in \{0, 1\}$ by the assumption.
2. $f(x)$ is non-decreasing in $x$.
3. $f(0) = \mu(\{0\}) = 0$ and $f(1) = \mu(\Omega) = 1$.

So, a simple argument shows that there exists $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ such that

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{for $x < \alpha$, and} \\
1 & \text{for $x > \alpha$.}
\end{cases} $$

(For example, set $\alpha = \inf\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 1\}$.) Then by fixing a sequence $(\varepsilon_n)$ of positive numbers decreasing to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, the continuity of $\mu$ shows that

\begin{align*}
\mu(\{\alpha\})
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu((\alpha - \varepsilon_n, \alpha + \varepsilon_n] \cap [0, 1]) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} [f(\alpha + \varepsilon_n) - f(\alpha - \varepsilon_n)] \\
&= 1,
\end{align*}

contradicting the assumption that $\mu(\{\alpha\}) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Does "non-decreasing" mean that it is monotonically increasing?

Comment: @Analysis, Indeed. It means that $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$. I prefer to use that word because some authors spare the term "increasing" for what is more commonly known as "strictly increasing".

Comment: That's what I thought.